# Razor-pages form is not hitting the post method

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

My post form is not working - the method in C# class is not even executing.
I tried some soutions I found, but still can't handle with that.

My simple view ReportBug.cshtml:

```
@page
@model Report

<div class="m-3 p-3">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h4 class="display-4">Report a bug</h4>
    </div>

    <form method="post">
        <div class="row">
            @(Html.Kendo()
                .TextBoxFor(t => t.Title)
                .Placeholder("Title")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 25%" })
            )
        </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

My C# class is:

```cs
public class ReportBugModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
    }

    public void OnPost(Report report)
    {
    }
}
```

as you can see I tried call this method with no parameter and with 1 parameter (Report model).
So summarizing:

- I have `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` in viewImports
- I tried tag helpers `asp-antiforgery="true"`

Before these post method were named `OnPostReport(Report report)` and I used tag helper `asp-page-handler="Report"`, but also failed.

So far after click `Submit` button my page is only reloading and I don't have any erros in console.

#Edit
Here is the generated HTML code:

```html
<div class="m-3 p-3">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h4 class="display-4">Report a bug</h4>
    </div>

    <form method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <span class="k-widget k-textbox" style="width: 25%;"><input id="Title" name="Title" style="width: 100%;" value="" data-role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" class="k-input" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="off"></span><script>kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#Title").kendoTextBox({"placeholder":"Title"});});</script>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8Bbl_ufFcklEjkehOGdz8BtSJK0b5YyLKm-ID2YYYWig_98ZBjFzd9-V_cDDrtBJqiKXJmW7blydpKIKa9qdz9sZZldP3cmya-BVho3uUIbW3_Ob-BVrLmAUi_KHq3eKEAE7nrELLwzebuzXTmnsP6sK2MubiEb3lK3mqOzmVERB2NmXvpI43QmwL-lGUr43Rw">
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: You can't have two methods named OnPost, even if one has a different signature. Razor Pages sees them as ambiguous. What is the generated HTML for your view page?

Comment: @MikeBrind I pasted generated HTML to the main post. Regarding to the two methods with the same name - I had one method before and didn't work, that's why I tried with two methods with different signatures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may misunderstand Razor Pages,please firstly learn the [get started document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#razor-pages):

For how to fix your issue,you could follow the steps below:

1.Change your Razor Pages `ReportBug.cshtml`(You must change `@model Report` to  `@model ReportBugModel`):

```
@page
@model ReportBugModel      //change here...
<div class="m-3 p-3">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h4 class="display-4">Report a bug</h4>
    </div>

    <form method="post">
        <div class="row">
            @(Html.Kendo()
                .TextBoxFor(t => t.Report.Title)    //also change here...
                .Placeholder("Title")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 25%" })
            )
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

2.Change your Razor Page backend code `ReportBug.cshtml.cs`:

```
public class ReportBugModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    public Report Report { get; set; }   //add this...
    public void OnPost(Report report)
    {
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]