# Can't get my Razor Page Form to hit my Post break point

Tags: c#, forms, post, razor-pages

I have looked at [Razor-pages form is not hitting the post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66711696/razor-pages-form-is-not-hitting-the-post-method) but it didn't help.

Waiver.cshtml

```
@page
@model GCRR.Models.WaiverLookup
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Waiver lookup page";
}

<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">
                Sign a new or lookup an existing liability waiver
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <br />
            <h3>
                If you have signed a waiver that included the participates that are with you today, adults and/or kids, then enter your phone number or email address to lookup your waiver. You will need this when purchasing tickets.
                If you have never signed a waiver before please click the new waiver button.
            </h3>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Phone" class="col-xs-12">Phone</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-9"><input asp-for="Phone" class="form-control" /></div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <br />or<br /><br />
                <div class="row form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Email">Email</label>
                    <div><input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" /></div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="row form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Waiver.cshtml.cs

```
using GCRR.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using GCRR.Models;

namespace GCRR.Pages
{
    public class WaiverModel : PageModel
    {
        private IWaiverFileService _waiverFileService;

        public WaiverModel(IWaiverFileService waiverFileService)
        {
            _waiverFileService = waiverFileService;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }

        public void OnPost(WaiverLookup waiverLookup)
        {
            var waivers = _waiverFileService.SearchWaiversAsync("8137812796");
        }

        //public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(WaiverLookup waiverLookup)
        //{
        //    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        //    {
        //        return Page();
        //    }

        //    // Do Something
        //    var waivers = await _waiverFileService.SearchWaiversAsync("8137812796");

        //    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        //}
    }
}
```

This is in Visual Studio 2022, I have a breakpoint set on the "OnPost" method but when I click the button the page refreshes and the breakpoint is not hit.

Has to be something dumb I'm missing here.  Even if I put an OnGet method with a breakpoint that is not hit either when the page loads.

Comment: Are you sure you are running in debug mode? `F5` instead of `Ctrl`+`F5` for example?

Comment: @Mike Brind, I wish it were that easy but no I'm definitely running in debug mode.  It's so very odd, guess should add this is VS 2022 but I can't imagine that making a difference.

Comment: Waiver.cshtml does not reference the right Page model.
It should be : @model GCRR.Pages.WaiverModel where the OnPost is defined

Comment: @GRFRM isn't the model just a class of where the data is held?  I made a separate "Models" folder and put the Waiver.cs in there was trying to have the Form data auto-populate the model

Comment: @GRFRM that does seem to fix it as long as I add the 2 form fields as properties of the page so thank you for that, Razor pages are new to me so now I'm just curious why I can't specify which class to use as the model for data and have to add the form fields as properties of the page but can use my class on the OnPost for passing the data in.  Seems redundent.

Comment: That the way Razor pages work. You can associate a PageModel class your page (cshtml) and you add your data class or properties to the PageModel class. It separates the view from the code

Comment: @GRFRM but I can't put my class for the data in it's own class in a models folder?  Right now it seems I have to have the property/class in the Waiver.cshtml and can't have that in it's own file in a models folder.

Comment: I added an answer to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave your WaiverLookup class in your Models folder.

In the WaiverModel class, add a property of type WaiverLookup

```
public class WaiverModel : PageModel
{
   public WaiverLookup WaiverLookup { get; set;} // Your new property !!!
 
   private IWaiverFileService _waiverFileService;

   public WaiverModel(IWaiverFileService waiverFileService)
   {
       _waiverFileService = waiverFileService;
   }

   public void OnGet()
   {
   }

   public void OnPost(WaiverLookup waiverLookup)
   {
      string phoneNumber = waiverLookup.Phone; // new value submitted

      var waivers = _waiverFileService.SearchWaiversAsync("8137812796");
   }
}
```

In your Waiver.cshtml page, you can now reference your new property WaiverLookup and access its members:

```
<input asp-for="WaiverLookup.Phone" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: Thank you this cleared up my confusion on how this is supposed to work.