# Razor Page Breakpoint Not Hitting OnGet/OnGetAsync Breakpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-7.0

So I have checked ([Can't get my Razor Page Form to hit my Post break point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70121064/cant-get-my-razor-page-form-to-hit-my-post-break-point)) before posting and mine doesn't hit the breakpoint on the Get method.

I have this URL: localhost:12345/mypage/123/guidvalue

This application is both a Web API and a single Razor page that returns a formatted view of a JSON file.

My Index.cshtml file is structured like this:

```
@page "mypage/{id:int}/{guidvalue}"
@model MyDTOObject
@{
 // Rest of the contents of the file
}
```

My Index.cshtml.cs looks like this:

```
        public MyDTOObject? Trace { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id, string guidvalue)
        {            
            Trace = await _someInterface.GetTrace(id, guidvalue);
            return Page();
        }

        // public IActionResult OnGet()
        // {
        //    Trace = _someInterface.GetTrace(1, new Guid(hardcodedvalue)).Result;
        //    return Page();
        // }
```

1. Since I have defined the path values in the cshtml file to map the route, I am expecting it would hit the OnGetAsync method breakpoint but it didn't.
2. I tried just loading the page without the route (and changing the @page attribute to just "mypage"), still the method without the parameters still didn't get hit. Anything that I am missing on this one?

I am using Visual Studio 2022, and Rider. Both doesn't hit the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

> Since I have defined the path values in the cshtml file to map the
> route, I am expecting it would hit the OnGetAsync method breakpoint
> but it didn't

Actually, when we create  any razor page it would autometically includes a [@page directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#razor-pages) within the particular page with [@page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#the-home-page) directive which means this would be the root entry of this very page that's also generate the route of /AnyPage

Now let's evaluate your scenario, you have the page called mypage along with two parameters and by convension the route would be as following:

```
@page "{id:int?}/{guidvalue?}"
```

> I tried just loading the page without the route (and changing the
> @page attribute to just "mypage"), still the method without the
> parameters still didn't get hit. Anything that I am missing on this
> one?

While you are defining with extra mypage directives like "mypage/{id:int}/{guidvalue}" your route pattern eventually got modified or changed. As you can see below:

[image]

Due to adding extra mypage directive your route certainly changed as following and you are no longer able to hit localhost:12345/mypage/123/guidvalue:

```
MyPage/mypage/{id:int}/{guidvalue}
```

[image]

**Note:** If you still want to get the route as per this defination @page "mypage/{id:int}/{guidvalue}" in that case you should hit with this URL localhost:12345/MyPage/mypage/123/guidvalue

**Solution:**

As expalined above, we don't need to include extra directive within the page again. So you can simply modify that as following:

```
@page "{id:int}/{guidvalue}"
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [Razor Pages Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-7.0) you could [check our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-7.0#additional-resources)